# Ubuntu app: WslRegisterDistribution failed with error 0x80070057 (incorrect parameter)

Tags: windows, ubuntu-20.04

I downloaded the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS from the Microsoft Store.
When I start the app in my Windows 10 (version 2004), I get this cryptic error:

> Installing, this may take a few minutes...
> WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80070057
> Error: 0x80070057 Falscher Parameter.

("Falscher Parameter" would be sth like incorrect parameter in English.)

I searched the web and StackOverflow but could not find a solution or even an explanation for this error.  I'd appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had I read the [installation instructions](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/ubuntu-2004-lts/9n6svws3rx71) earlier, I would have found this:

> To use this feature, one first needs to use "Turn Windows features on
> or off" and select "**Windows Subsystem for Linux**", click OK, reboot,
> and use this app.
>
> The above step can also be performed using Administrator PowerShell
> prompt:
> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName
> Microsoft-Windows-Subsystem-Linux

I used the PowerShell prompt and was able to start the Ubuntu app right away, without reboot.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried all the solutions, all of them. From restarting `LXSS` to new installation. Nothing worked, what worked was a simple rename. If your previous folder with linux subsystem was named something like `ubuntu` and you want to install it again, change the name to something else.

**powershell command:**

> ren ubuntu xxd`

*Basic folder/zip renaming solved the problem*

Answer (score 1):

Try running the following command from an MS-DOS console as an administrator:

bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto

reboot Windows 10 and start the UBUNTU app again.

Warning: if you have an Ubuntu virtual machine in Oracle VM VirtualBox, that virtual machine will stop working. To make it work again you will have to put just the opposite instruction:

bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off

Answer (score 0):

The 'error 0x80070057' in my case, I want to install WSL to SD card (or external storage). it is wrong and not allowed now.

just install to HDD(C: drive) and solved it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try running the following command in an administrative command prompt to set the default version of WSL to 1:

`wsl --set-default-version 1`

After that, you can try installing the distribution of your choice again using the following command:

`wsl --install -d <distribution>`